# How to use import statement instead of require TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
 const proxyquire = require('proxyquireify')(require);
```

I'm using proxyquire to mock dependencies for jasmine in unit testing. When i use the code mentioned above, I'm getting some errors because of using 'require' method.

Is there any way to use import statement for this scenario instead of require or is there any alternative to proxyquire?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? You probably have to install `@types/node`

Comment: @lleon when i build the project with gulp, it cannot identify require method and required modules. It won't show any compile or run time error

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code to reproduce the error?

Comment: `const proxyquire = require('proxyquireify')(require);

describe('Experiences Test', () => {
  let experiencesMock: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    experiencesMock = proxyquire('./Experiences', {
      loglevel: {
        getLogger: mockFunctions.spyGetLogger,
        setLevel: mockFunctions.spySetLevel
      }
    });`